# How do I switch my theme based on data from local storage

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage

My theme settings always revert to the default theme on page refresh despite reading the theme settings from local storage

Here is my code for the theme implementation:

```
green.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('theme') != 'green') {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'green');
  }
  main.classList.add(localStorage.getItem('theme'));
});
yellow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('theme') !== 'yellow') {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'yellow');
  }
  main.className = localStorage.getItem('theme');
});
purple.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('theme') !== '') {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', '');
  }
  main.className = localStorage.getItem('theme');
});
```

I've checked the localStorage and the theme values are stored

Comment: What is the initial class? You need to set the class on page load as well depending upon the value.

Comment: The initial class is an empty string

Comment: You need to initialize your local storage variable with the default theme. In your Initial class read the theme from the local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Initial class instead of setting it to empty, set the local storage to the default theme and read the theme value from local storage in your initial class. So that on page reload also you will be reading the theme from the local storage and it will be set already with the custom theme.